# Should I use trim() when I get header fields from $ _SERVER?

Tags: php, http

[RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2):

> Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name
> followed    by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field
> value, and    optional trailing whitespace.

Comment: A bit of trimming has never hurt anyone... :-)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware 95 kilo's. Do I need trimming?

Comment: On a serious note: there is no need for it, but if you feel better, you could always use `trim()`. It does no harm and is processed in a split of a second.